# IE Compatibility mode is preventing me getting my error messages

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, web-applications

I have a JavaScript web app that dosen't run on IE.

So naturally I fire up the console to try to figure out what is wrong.  However, by some annoying miracle, it decides to work when I do this.

I believe it enters some compatibility mode when the console is open wich fixes the error thus preventing me from findin out what is wrong.  Here is all I got from the console:

> HTML1200: dropbox.com is on the Internet Explorer 9 Compatibility View List ('C:\Users...\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\IECompatData\iecompatdata.xml').

- How do I prevent this happening?

or..

- can somone tell me why [my app](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/18600785/PANOTA/panota.html) isnt working :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script you have got `console.log()`. The `console` is only available in IE8 / 9 if the developer tools are open:

```
console.log(model); // line 104
console.log("Days to complete: " + days); // line 310
```

All you need to do is remove the `console.log()` statements.

Comment: Awesome thanks.  Is there any way to conditionally include the logs for non IE browsers?  Also how did you find this out? Manual inspection?

Comment: Yep, pretty much through painful experience; as with most things in IE :-). You could include a `function` something like: `function log(msg) {
    if (typeof console !== "undefined") {
        console.log(msg);
    }
}` and then do `log(model)`. When it comes to production you'd want to remove it though.